# boolean method with array argument

Tags: java, arrays, methods, boolean

I am trying for too long to figure out this exersies but I am stuck here. I need to write a boolean method that will an array as argument and should return true if numbers in array are in decreasing order. Bu any time that I am trying I am having the same value or errors. Here is my code:

```
public class Question1c{
    public static void main (String[] args){
        int[] arr = {1, 9, 3, 4, 5, 6};
        boolean product = isDecreasing(arr);
        System.out.println(product);
    }

    public static boolean isDecreasing (int[] numbers){
        int first = numbers[0];

        for (int i : numbers){

            if(first <= i){
                first = i;
                return true;
            }

            //else{
            //  return false;
            //}
        }return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: whats the error that you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you cannot return `true` until after you went through the entire array. However, you can return `false` as soon as you detect an "inversion" - i.e. a situation when the number that follows the one you've seen before is *greater* than the prior number.

You are reasonably close to a working solution - you need to remove `return true`, uncomment the `else`, and change the final `return false` to `return true`.

To make your code more readable, rename `first` to `prior`. Also consider changing the "foreach" version of the `for` loop to a regular `for` loop that skips the initial element of the array. This would let you detect decreasing order, as opposed to non-increasing, which you currently detect.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand, but wouldn't this solve your issue?

```
public class Question1c{
    public static void main (String[] args){
        int[] arr = {1, 9, 3, 4, 5, 6};
        boolean product = isDecreasing(arr);
        System.out.println(product);
    }

    public static boolean isDecreasing (int[] numbers){
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++){
            if (i == 0)
                continue;
            if (numbers[i - 1] >= numbers[i])
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

You're essentially just aiming to check that the previous item in the array isn't greater than or equal to the current item in the array, aren't you?

Answer (score 1):

You initialize first with `numbers[0]` this causes several problems:

- An empty array throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException`
- the first check automatically passes (`numbers[0] <= numbers[0]`)

you best check the length of `numbers` for 0 and use a "normal" for loop (using an index).

Your return values is also the negation of what it should be.

Answer (score 1):

This might solve your issue.

```
public class Question{
public static void main (String[] args){
    int[] arr = {1, 9, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    boolean product = isDecreasing(arr);
    System.out.println(product);
```

}

```
public static boolean isDecreasing (int[] numbers){
    int first = numbers[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length ; i++) {

        if (first <= numbers[i]) {
            return false;
        } 
        first = numbers[i];
    }
    return true;
}
```

}